# ¿Cómo convertir una palabra en pirámide, escribiendo cada vez un carácter más?

Tags: python

Escriba un programa que dada una frase la imprima en forma de pirámide, como se muestra en el ejemplo.

Ingrese una frase: `hola`

```
h
ho
hol
hola
```

Lo qué logré  hacer hasta el momento es convertir la frase a una lista, y luego con un bucle for quería imprimir cada indice e ir sumandole el siguiente:

```
pal=input("Ingrese una frase: ")
lista=list(pal)
for a in range(len(lista)):
    lista[a]=lista[a]+1
    print(lista[a])
```

pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Para ver una lista por posiciones podrías intentar convertirlo a string, de esta manera=
print(str(lista[i])). Aunque creo que tu error esta en la forma en que manejas las posiciones de la lista, sin embargo...¿Por qué no creas una variable que guarde los caracteres mientras recorres la lista? eso es más fácil, de esta manera:

```
pal=input("Ingrese una frase: ")
lista=list(pal)
palabra = ""
for i in range(len(lista)):
    palabra = palabra+lista[i]
    print(palabra)
```

Ya lo probé y si me funciona, espero te sirva! jeje

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario convertir la frase a lista, ni a otra estructura de datos para iterar sobre sus elementos, porque una cadena de caracteres en Python ya es un iterable:

```
pal = "abcde"
for i in pal:
    print(s)
```

Resultado: **a b c d e** (una letra por linea)

Para imprimir lo que pides simplemente hay que ir acumulando en una variable:

```
pal = input("Ingrese una frase: ")
cad = ""
for i in pal:
    cad += i
    print(cad)
```

Da como resultado:

```
Ingrese una frase: stack
s
st
sta
stac
stack
```

---

Por otro lado, Python no es el lenguaje que es hoy en día por gusto, así que ese código en realidad se puede escribir con instrucciones más potentes, como el uso de [fstrings](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-24) (Python 3.6+).
Las fstrings son muy versátiles, puedes imprimir, redondear, rellenar, alinear, tabular, etc, de una forma más eficiente y clara para el programador.

Por ejemplo, la misma cadena alineada a la derecha:

```
word = input("Ingrese una frase: ")
longitud = len(word)

for i in range(1, longitud+1):
    print(f"{word[:i]:{' '}>{longitud}}")
```

Resultado:

```
Ingrese una frase: stack
    s
   st
  sta
 stac
stack
```

`>` alineado a la derecha, `<` alineado a la izquierda, `^` centrado. El caracter vacio `' '` significa que se va a rellenar con espacios en blanco las partes que no tienen contenido.

Answer (score 0):

debes crear una variable **Contador=0** que recorra las posiciones de la lista, desde la posición 0. Ya que actualmente el codigo `lista[a]=lista[a]+1` lo que estas haciendo es sumarle 1 a la lista. Adicional, en el momento de la impresión asignarle el rango desde la posición inicial de lista hasta la posición del contador, la solución que se me ocurre es la siguiente

```
contador=0
lista=list(input("inserte una frase: "))

for a in range(len(lista)):
    imprimir=lista
    print(lista[:contador])
    contador=contador+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo 20 minutos aprendiendo python y en uno de los primeros vídeos que vi aprendí esta simpleza

```
palabra = "anticonstitucionalmente"
piramide = ""

for item in palabra:
  piramide += item
  print(piramide)
```